# New Images (on Windows) Receive 404 Response from Tomcat

Tags: windows, tomcat, jpeg, malware, virus

SOLUTION: Reinstalled Tomcat. I must admit that I didn't solve the details of this problem. Something went wrong. Eventually, it looked like something with the server wasn't working. I never figured it out. But reinstalling the server (actually I upgraded to v9) got it working properly again.

UPDATE: Made a copy of the ROOT directory (Tomcat webapps) and the copy works fine. Then I changed the name of ROOT to a backup and the name of the copy to ROOT. The problem exists with the copy.

Windows 7  Tomcat 8   Java 8

To be honest, I need a hint. I've been running a web shop for several years. Now suddenly I'm getting 404 responses from Tomcat on new images. The images are in the same folders as they have been all along. The most recent test was to simply copy-paste an existing image (which Tomcat serves properly) in the folder and rename it. Tomcat responds with 404 on the copy (but not the original).

I've checked permissions on the image files. The folder has more than 7K images (NTFS) - in theory, that shouldn't be a problem. Just to be sure, I deleted a dozen that were out of date. No change. I ran chkdsk and used a second disk analyzer just in case. The images can be viewed with Microsoft photo-viewer and Paint. I've even save-replaced with Paint - no change. I've tried clearing browser caches and even Tomcat's cache (which doesn't seem to contain images) and set Resources cachingAllowed="false" within the Context tag (context.xml) It seems that my final simple test says everything I know about the problem at this point. Tomcat returns 404 on new images.

Note: Testing is not being done through the web shop software. I simply type the web address of the image in the browser address bar. It's then just a matter of Tomcat serving the image. There are no differences in the addresses except for the image file names.

UPDATE: Ran Malwarebytes ... no evidence of malware at this point. Running Panda full-time.

Comment: Compare the permissions on a working/non-working file & see if they differ. Running processmonitor on the tomcat process and watching its file-system access would show you if the request results in an attempted file system read & any reasons for its failure.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to mention that I've checked permissions. I'll try the process monitor when I'm back on the job tomorrow. Sounds like it might lead to a hint. BTW: I'll change my question to mention that I've checked permissions.

Comment: Perhaps the `mime-mapping` for the new images have not been defined in the `web.xml` file?

Comment: All the other jpg images work. Been working for years now.

Comment: I haven't used Process Monitor before, but it looks like I got slightly lucky and am looking at the first results. I selected Tomcat in Process Tree and am seeing some of the problem files listed after opening the web shop in the browser. (Don't have enough control of this tool yet to run my simple experiment. Not getting updated results.) I'm getting Fast IO Disallowed and NAME NOT FOUND ... Type QueryDirectory, Filter 24656.jpg (which is the name of an existing file.) DETAILS: http://mopedum.se/IMAGE_EVENT.txt